# Pour toutes les femmes que j'ai aimées un jour

Tags: syntaxe, paroles-de-chanson

Dans la comédie musicale « Cindy », il y a une chanson entitulée « Un homme qui passe » ([vidéo](https://youtu.be/TUVZaJcd9e4?t=71), [paroles](https://www.paroles-musique.com/eng/Cindy_Cendrillon-Un_Homme_Qui_Passe-lyrics,p17273)) où cet homme dit :

> Pour toutes les femmes que j'ai aimées un jour
>   
> J'ai toujours été un homme qui passe

Il me semble que « pour » ici donne plusieurs interprétations syntaxiques :

1. Aux yeux de ces femmes, je ne suis qu'un homme qui passe
2. Chères femmes : Je révèle maintenant que je suis un homme qui passe
3. En raison de ces femmes, je suis un homme qui passe
4. Malgré mon amour pour toutes ces femmes, je suis un homme qui passe

   *Je crois que ce serait un anglicisme : "For all the love I felt, I'm still nothing but..."*
5. Afin d'avoir ces femmes, j'ai été un homme qui passe
6. Autres ?

Laquelle vous semble la plus probable, s'il est bien possible de choisir entre elles ?

Comment: Selon moi l'interprétation 4 serait plus qu'un anglicisme, c'est juste une forme qui ne convient pas du tout pour exprimer cette idée en français...

Comment: @Laurent Six of one, half a dozen of the other :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La 3 et la 4 ne me semblent pas possibles, et je n'en vois pas d'autres.

En revanche la 1, la 2 et la 5 sont possibles grammaticalement (bien que la 5 serait plutôt "Par amour pour ces femmes", "Pour faire plaisir à ces femmes", un acte généreux plutôt qu'une stratégie malicieuse).

Le "j'ai toujours" indique cependant que c'était déjà le cas avant et ce sera toujours le cas après, donc on peut écarter le comportement adopté *pour* ces femmes.

Selon moi, la 1 et la 2 sont possibles, mais la 1 est plus probable. Sinon, la formulation "*À toutes les femmes que j'ai aimées, ...*" aurait été préférée.

Comment: For 5, I don't quite see your objection. If it was "j'ai toujours choisi d'être", for example, wouldn't it be the same temporal relationship? Toujours as in dans chaque cas

Comment: Torn b/w this and jlliagre's, but they come to the same thing & this has mor explanation (though I would like to know your answer to my comment above)

Answer (score 8):

Je ne vois pas d'autres interprétations que celles décrites dans la question et la seule qui me paraît plausible dans cette chanson est la première :

> Aux yeux de toutes les femmes que j'ai aimées un jour...

Comment: Le dictionnaire par d'une forme de pour `En tant qu'instance d'évaluation`, qui correspond bien à ce "aux yeux de". (je précise je cherchais si "pour" fonctionnait aussi pour `à l'encontre` / `à l'intention` / `appliqué aux` et je n'ai pas trouvé ce sens dans le dictionnaire. (`avec` semblerait plus approprié pour cette version).

Comment: For the 3rd one, consider this lyric by the same lyricist (Luc Plamondon): « Toi, tu leur ressembles, tu me plaît **pour ça**. » Would this use of "pour" as a cause/explanation change not work here, even as a less likely alternative to #1?

Comment: *En raison de* "something" is idiomatic but *en raison de* "someone" is quite not. When referring to people, "because of" translates to either *à cause de* (negative) or *grâce à* (positive).

Comment: @jlliagre Good to know as far as my reformulation with *en raison de*. Are you saying the same applies to *pour* + *personne* in the song?

Comment: Yes, #3 (and #4) do not work.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai écouté la vidéo jusqu'au bout et il en ressort qu'il regrette de ne jamais avoir pu donner d'amour.
C'est un marin, il s'en va donc obligatoirement.
La réponse de Jlliagre me plaît.
Il parle à sa fille: Le "Pour" est un moyen pour cet homme d'indiquer qu'il n'a jamais pu rester auprès d'une femme qu'il a côtoyé et aimé.

Je pense que les deux phrases sont inversées pour souligner le fait qu'il a aimé ces femmes sans pouvoir leur transmettre son amour.
=> J'ai toujours été un homme qui passe pour toutes les femmes que j'ai aimées un jour.